# How to insert Dates in mysql DB with mysql2?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mysql2

When making a query to a mysql db (with node/mysql2):

```
.query(
      "INSERT INTO expenses (expense_date, expense_value, user_id) VALUES ?",
      ["06-08-2022", 11.33, "2"],
      true
    )
```

I get the following error:
`sqlMessage: "Incorrect date value: '06-08-2022' for column 'expense_date' at row 1"``

I understand we need to let mysql know we are handling a Date by using probably the STR_TO_DATE method.

However, I´m not sure how to do it in mysql2

Comment: MySQL dates are always `YYYY-MM-DD` as you are hard coding those into an array, just fix the format

Comment: This deserves to be an answer, not a comment. You may and should fix that. This comment will self destruct in 24 hours.

Comment: @ITgoldman Its really common knowledge after your first mistake. I would be more tempted to close the question as a TYPO

Comment: @RiggsFolly it worked thanks! If you want you can add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as a solution